# Regex to pull the first and last letter of a string

Tags: python, regex, string, sequence

I am using this `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}` to validate my string. It works to pull the sequence of numbers out of said string resulting in 02-01-1716 however, i also need to pull the letter the string begins with and ends with; **i.e.** **Q**:\Region01s\FY 02\02-01-1716**A**.pdf i need the Q as well as the A so in the end i would have Q: 02-01-1716A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
regex = r"^([a-zA-Z]:)\\(?:.*\\)?(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}[a-zA-Z]?)"
text = r"Q:\Region01s\FY 02\02-01-1716A.pdf"
match = re.search(regex, text)
if match:
    print(f"{match.group(1)} {match.group(2)}")

# => Q: 02-01-1716A
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RLJqLj). Also, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QYcDGH/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([a-zA-Z]:)` - Group 1: a letter and `:`
- `\\` - a backslash
- `(?:.*\\)?` - an optional sequence of any chars other than line break chars as many as possible, followed with a backslash
- `(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}[a-zA-Z]?)` - Group 2: two digits, `-`, two digits, `-`, four digits, an optional letter.

The output - if there is a match - is a concatenation of Group 1, space and Group 2 values.

Comment: how would i edit this to open and read a text document rather than only reading one specific text line but still get the same output?

Comment: @HEB [Like this](https://ideone.com/sMUrry).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
(.).*(.)\.[^\.]+$
```

Or with the validation:

```
(.).*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}(.)\.[^\.]+$
```

Comment: this results in the output [('Q', 'A')] however i need something along the lines of Q: 02-01-1716A, i realize my original question didn't necessarily specify that so i edited it

Comment: Then `(.:).*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}.)\.[^\.]+$`